# How could I get a list of the shells in my operating system?

Tags: shell

Say I use some Linux operating system. How could I see a list of **all** the shells that came installed with it (**either** CLI shells or GUI shells)?

Typing `echo $SHELL` isn't good for me because it only shows me my current shell (Bash), but what I desire is to list all shells currently installed in the system.

My aim is to have a direct check of all the shells that came with my OS, especially if there are any other beside `sh` and `Bash`.

Comment: The linked thread and others I've seen doesn't give a way to list **both** CLI shells and GUI shells (an example - Gnome shell or Unity shell).

Comment: This is not a matter of the kernel (so Linux is irrelevant).

Comment: If you feel a question was closed incorrectly, please open a discussion on [meta] explaining why you feel that way. Flags are only for moderators (users with a ♦ after their name) but closing is usually done by regular users. That said, I'm afraid your question won't be answerable because while they are both called shells and both will provide a way to interact with the machine, they are quite different things and you won't find a list of all graphical and CLI shells like this.You might want to try these questions in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
chsh -l
```

`chsh` allows you to change for a given user but `chsh -l` simply lists the shell that are available.

If `chsh -l` isn't supported on your distribution, then `cat /etc/shells` should achieve the same result.

Comment: Or `cat /etc/shells`

Comment: `chsh: invalid option -- 'l'`

Comment: `-l` is a valid for `util-linux`’s `chsh` (as used in Fedora etc.), not for `shadow-utils`’ (as used in Debian etc.).

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/329479/38062 and observe that the questioner is asking about _more_ than just TUI shells.

Comment: Sorry, I admit I added the demand to GUI shells as well in an edit (that was I meant in the first place but misphrased). Anyway, what is TUI, @JdeBP (did you mean GUI or TUI)?

Comment: _Textual User Interface_.